# loop through all entries of AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Object>

Tags: java

I want to loop through all entries of AbstractMap.SimpleEntry type and Map type using the same  function. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate through what you are asking. I am guessing you mean the following:

```
for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry : AbstractMap.entrySet()) {
   K key = entry.getKey();
   V value = entry.getValue();
}
```

This example will not run; you'll need to alter it to your concrete implementations of the Abstract classes and Key/Value definitions.

[Oracle Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html)

[Another Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map?rq=1)

Comment: Yes Its AbstractMap.SimpleEntry object. Yes you are right.  I want to loop through (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Object> object and check each entry. I basically want to serialize it. So what should I do?